# Winforms BindingSource .AddNew() works but .CancelNew() does nothing

Tags: winforms, bindingsource

Per screen capture below:

1. `bindingSource1.AddNew()` works as expected. A new item appears and becomes current.
2. `bindingSource1.CancelNew()` **does nothing**. Per debug messages my button handler is clearly being called, and it correctly attempts to cancel list index 3, but the new user is not actually removed.

The same problem occurs regardless of whether `bindingSource1` is backed by `BindingList<User>` or `List<User>` (shown).

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Adding `((IEditableObject)_newlyAdded).CancelEdit()` just prior to the `CancelNew()` does not help either.

Comment: The `CancelNew()` implementation is just `RemoveAt(index)`, why are you not using that? Does `AllowRemove` return `true`?

Comment: `AllowRemove` does indeed return true for both `BindingList<User>` and `List<User>`. Not sure what you mean by the remainder of your comment. Why would they bother explicitly implementing `ICancelAddNew` on `BindingSource` if you weren't meant to call it?

Comment: Why would you bother to call this method that is not exposed directly, when the actual implementation is `RemoveAt([Index])`? BTW, this is what the explicit implementation does

Comment: In addition to `RemoveAt()`, it is managing some internal metadata for an `addNewPos` variable: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,2099

Comment: That's not metadata, it's just a private Field. The same Field value is copied to the `Position` Property when `AddNew()` is called -- Use the actual implementation instead, which, btw, covers it all and more